# How to make openjdk-8 default java version and remove openjdk-7

Tags: openjdk

I have intalled openjdk-8 (from official repo) with `apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk`

and updated alternatives with `update-alternatives --config java`

now

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections|grep java
appletviewer                   auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer
extcheck                       auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/extcheck
idlj                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/idlj
itweb-settings                 auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings
jar                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar
jarsigner                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner
java                           manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
java2groovy                    auto     /usr/share/groovy/bin/java2groovy
javac                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
javadoc                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
javah                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah
javap                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap
javaws                         auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws
jcmd                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jcmd
jconsole                       auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
jdb                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb
jdeps                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdeps
jexec                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec
jhat                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jhat
jinfo                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo
jjs                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jjs
jmap                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap
jps                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps
jrunscript                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jrunscript
jsadebugd                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jsadebugd
jstack                         auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstack
jstat                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat
jstatd                         auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd
keytool                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
mozilla-javaplugin.so          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
native2ascii                   auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/native2ascii
orbd                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd
pack200                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200
policytool                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool
rmic                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmic
rmid                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid
rmiregistry                    auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry
schemagen                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/schemagen
serialver                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver
servertool                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool
tnameserv                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv
unpack200                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/unpack200
wsgen                          auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen
wsimport                       auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsimport
xjc                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/xjc
```

so a lot of tool still use java 7. How to make java 8 the real/default version ?
May be reinstall java 8 so that it is automatically set to be default instead of changing each alternatives to java 8 ?

Moreover, when I try to remove java 7, apt-get tries to remove a lot of packages:

```
# apt-get purge openjdk-7-jreheadless openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant ant-optional antlr aspectj bnd bsh checkstyle fop ivy java-wrappers junit junit4 libaether-java libantlr-java libaopalliance-java libapache-pom-java
  libasm3-java libasm4-java libaspectj-java libasync-http-client-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java libavalon-framework-java libbatik-java libbcel-java
  libbcpg-java libbcprov-java libbindex-java libbsf-java libbsh-java libcdi-api-java libcglib-java libclassworlds-java libcommons-beanutils-java
  libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-configuration-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-digester-java
  libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-io-java libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-jxpath-java libcommons-lang-java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-net2-java
  libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java libcommons-vfs-java libconstantine-java libdom4j-java libdoxia-java libeasymock-java libecj-java libfop-java
  libganymed-ssh2-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-osgi-support-java
  libgnuinet-java libgnujaf-java libgnumail-java libgoogle-gson-java libguava-java libguice-java libhamcrest-java libhawtjni-runtime-java libhttpclient-java
  libhttpcore-java libitext1-java libjackrabbit-java libjaffl-java libjansi-java libjansi-native-java libjarjar-java libjatl-java libjaxen-java libjaxp1.3-java
  libjcifs-java libjcip-annotations-java libjcommander-java libjdom1-java libjetty-extra libjetty-extra-java libjetty-java libjffi-java libjffi-jni libjline-java
  libjna-java libjnr-posix-java libjnr-x86asm-java libjsch-agent-proxy-java libjsch-java libjsoup-java libjsr305-java libkryo-java liblog4j1.2-java
  liblogback-java libmaven-ant-tasks-java libmaven-parent-java libmaven-scm-java libmaven2-core-java libminlog-java libmockobjects-java libmodello-java
  libmx4j-java libnative-platform-java libnative-platform-jni libnekohtml-java libnetbeans-cvsclient-java libnetty-java libobjenesis-java libosgi-compendium-java
  libosgi-core-java libosgi-foundation-ee-java libplexus-ant-factory-java libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-build-api-java
  libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-cli-java libplexus-container-default-java libplexus-containers-java
  libplexus-containers1.5-java libplexus-i18n-java libplexus-interactivity-api-java libplexus-interpolation-java libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java
  libplexus-utils-java libplexus-utils2-java libpolyglot-maven-java libqdox-java libreflectasm-java libregexp-java librhino-java libsaxon-java libservlet2.5-java
  libservlet3.0-java libsisu-guice-java libsisu-ioc-java libslf4j-java libtomcat7-java libwagon-java libwagon2-java libxalan2-java libxbean-java libxerces2-java
  libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxom-java libxpp2-java libxpp3-java libxstream-java
  libyaml-snake-java maven rhino testng
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra
Suggested packages:
  sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-indic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-jre-headless* gradle* groovy* icedtea-7-jre-jamvm* icedtea-7-plugin* icedtea-netx* icedtea-plugin* libcodenarc-groovy-java* libgmetrics-groovy-java*
  libgradle-core-java* libgradle-plugins-java* openjdk-7-jdk* openjdk-7-jre* openjdk-7-jre-headless*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 14 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 38.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

How to avoid that ? And It wants to install **java 6** ? How to avoid that also ?

Comment: I have the same problem. What I really want is to, when I double-click a .jar, it will by default open in OpenJDK 8 - it's not really clear, but I'm guessing that's what your asking from the title. [link](http://i.imgur.com/6tjtRYW.png)

Comment: I just did `sudo update-alternatives --all` and manually changed everything to java 8, but I'm not sure it helped.

Comment: `groovy` seems to be a culprit: it depends on `default-jre-headless | sun-java6-jre` (and default is 7)